# How to make the left margin "appear" outside the container div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Notice how when using Bootstrap, the row div inside the container div have the left margin "appear" outside the container div (the left margin is the yellow part):

[image]

I tried to replicate this behavior using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #div1
            {
                width: 500px;
                height: 400px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            #div2
            {
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: red;
                margin-right: 100px;
                margin-left: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <div id="div2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it did not work (the left margin stayed inside the container div):

[image]

Comment: bootstrap uses negative values for the left/right margins on `.row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using margins with negative value like this:

```
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the same value for padding-left padding-right on div1 based on negative  margin-left , margin-right value of div2. 
check the snippet I have remove added media query and box-sizing for better view. and remove the width for div2 and set inital width

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
body{
 margin:0;
}
 #div1
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding-right: 100px;
            padding-left:100px;    
        }

        #div2
        {
           
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            margin-right: -100px;
            margin-left: -100px;
        }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

#div1 {
    width: 81.584%;
}
}
```

```html
 <div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
```